# Django - Can't retrieve Many to Many field from Queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have the following code:

```py
exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(teacher=request.user.id).values('id', 'question', 'ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3', 'correct', 'unit', 'resol', 'theme', 'img')
```

This works fine, but the "theme" is a Many to Many Field, the format returns `{ ..., theme: value }` instead of `{ ..., theme: [value1, value2] }`

What should I implement to get the desired format?

Comment: I'd use a serializer for this. If you use `values`, django will do a left join that will return one row per theme per exercise

Comment: And how could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by doing the following:

```py
try:
    exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(teacher=request.user.id)
    ids = exercises.values_list('id', flat=True)

    reloaded_qs = Exercise.objects.all()
    reloaded_qs.query = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(ids.query))
    exercise_serializer = ExerciseSerializer(exercises, many=True)

    if exercise_serializer.is_valid:
        for val, q in enumerate(reloaded_qs):
            exercise_serializer.data[val].update(q)

except BaseException as e:
    return JsonResponse({ 'v': False, 'm': str(e) }, safe=False)
 
return JsonResponse(exercise_serializer.data, safe=False)
```